# Insert text with space from resource file to the value property of input in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, resources

I have the following code to insert text from resource file to the value property of input in MVC  4:

```html
<input type="submit" value=@EXAMPLE.Resources.Account.Login.SignInText />
```

The text is in spanish: "Iniciar Sesion", however only shows "Iniciar" because between "Iniciar" and "Sesion" exist one space character.

Any Idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around your attribute value:

```
<input type="submit" value="@EXAMPLE.Resources.Account.Login.SignInText" />
```

You should ALWAYS use quotes for attributes IMHO, don't omit them.

Comment: Thank you. He has been very helpful